# How to clean up/optimize/defrag $Extend\RmMetadata\$Txf files?

Tags: windows, windows-10, filesystems, ntfs, defragment

After analyzing my HDD using Auslogics Disk Defrag, I see a lot of many small files with no file extensions.

Their paths are mostly `C:\$Extend\$RmMetadata\$Txf\..` File names start with `000000000[xxxx]`

Is there a way to defrag all of them or move to one place/optimize ? You can see in the screenshot - every gray block contains these files. I tried boot defrag using Defraggler and Auslogics Disk defrag, but nothing changed.

[image]

Comment: The screenshot says they are not fragmented and are unmovable, leave them alone as they are critical windows files.

Comment: [How do I defragment "C:\$Extend\$RmMetadata\$TxfLog\$Tops:$T:$DATA"?](https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/36535-how-do-i-defragment-c-extend-rmmetadata-txflog-tops-t-data)

Comment: I saw that before already, he asked about $Tops:$T:$DATA file or files which I don't even have in that huge amount. I couldn't find anything about this on the web, so I'm asking here.

Comment: @Moab These files cause other files to be fragmented, they are scattered all over the front part of the disk, so if those all files would be located at the end there would be empty blocks in the front part...

Comment: that are internal data for Transactional NTFS: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transactional_NTFS ignore those internal data